# Value of series, Partialsum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

given is the following series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}$$

And I need to find its value.

How can I start finding it?

Thanks for all

---

does the Telescop-Summing work here as well?:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4n^2-1} $
now:
$\frac{1}{4n^2-1} = \frac{1}{2} * \frac{(2n+1)-(2n-1)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)} = \frac{1}{2} * ( \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1})$

Now I have to "add the sum":
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4n^2-1} = \frac{1}{2}* [ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n-1} - 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}] =  \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4n+2} $ And than for $n \to \infty$ it is $\frac{1}{2}$ ??

Answer (score 7):

HINT:
$$\frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}$$

Can you recognize [Telescoping Sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html)?

Comment: Hi, that's a huge hint, thank you very much! :) If I am right, than using the 'Telescoping Sum' in the end I get: $1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ and now I look at $ n \to \infty $ and I get: The Value is 1.

Comment: @KevinLiebing, welcome. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

split it up the numerator to 2n + 2 - 1 then factor to 2(n+1) -1.
By spliting the fraction you can cancel terms.
This should allow you to see this is a finite result.

Comment: Are you suggesting that we go $\frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\frac{2(n+1)-1}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\frac{2-1}{n^2(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$?...!